# how to make a parallel branch in git

Tags: git, version-control, github, branch, git-branch

I want to make a parallel 'dev' branch off of the primary 'prod' branch. So I did

```
git checkout -b dev prod
```

Which I would think would make a 'branch' coming off of 'prod' in parallel that should be called 'dev'.

However when I look at my project in 'SourceTree' I just see one straight branch.

I thought 'well maybe because dev is technically the same as prod still, that is why there is just one straight branch. Maybe i need to commit a file to the dev branch, and then I will see two branches in parallel'. So, I changed one file with my HEAD on dev and did
    git add someFile.m
    git commit

Then in source tree I get another 'node' above the current branch, but I still see one straight branch (no parallel 'dev' and 'prod' branches)

When I do 
    git status
I see
    dev
    master
    prod
    remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
    remotes/origin/master
    remotes/origin/prod

Any ideas how to have a parallel working copy of dev running next to prod?

(p.s I also tried using the sourcetree UI. I clicked on 'Branch', but even so I don't find two parallel branches, just one single branch.)

Comment: What is the motivation for this parallel branch?  You could potentially write a script that automatically rebases the second branch onto the first branch periodically.

Comment: The motivation is this architecture: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 3):

In git a "branch" is no "line" which could be parallel to another "branch-line".

In git a "branch" is just a name of some commit.

Those lines are drawn by SourceTree to visualize which commit is the parent of which commit.

A simple `git checkout -b dev prod` will do not much more that giving the current commit a second name.

If you want to see parallel lines, you have to add commits to both branches. - Then SourceTree will draw those lines.

Comment: You are right (in a way) I actually had to do commits to '''both''' the 'dev' and the 'prod' branch before they would appear as two separate but parallel branches, so I had to do:

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout -b dev prod
```

Creates a 'dev' branch that has the same source code as 'prod' - however in SourceTree and other visualizers, you will not see two branches running in parallel until you first commit some change on both branches - committing a change on one of the branches is not enough to see branches running in parallel. For example

```
git checkout -b dev prod
```

(Now edit a file in the dev branch called someFile.m and save it)

```
git add someFile.m
git commit someFile.m
```

(Now switch to the production branch)

```
git checkout prod
```

(Now edit someFile.m and save it)

```
git add someFile.m
git commit someFile.m
```

Now when you visualize your git branches, you will see 'dev' and 'prod' running in parallel.